# GCP Cloud Scheduler API Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to test setting up GCP Cloud Scheduler Jobs via terraform and am discovering issues when trying to create via the API. I am also testing the API in on this page: [projects.locations.jobs/create](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/create). The errors I am seeing are around an invalid argument:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Job name must be formatted: \"projects/\u003cPROJECT_ID\u003e/locations/\u003cLOCATION_ID\u003e/jobs/\u003cJOB_ID\u003e\".",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I then modify to fit that format and see this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Resource name should start with \"/projects/\u003cPROJECT_ID\u003e/\"",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Here's what the request body looks like:

```
{
  "name": "projects/<my-project-id>/locations/us-central1/jobs/snapshots",
  "pubsubTarget": {
    "topicName": "disk-snapshot-function-trigger",
    "attributes": {
      "num_backups": "5",
      "project": "<my-project-id>"
    }
  },
  "schedule": "0 19 * * *",
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
}
```

There's really no winning, all requests get ERROR 400.

Comment: How is terraform involved with this problem? Remove that tag. Your `topicName` is formatted incorrectly `projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_ID`

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to get it to work in Terraform by adding the `project/PROEJCT_ID/topics/TOPIC_ID` prefex to the pubsub topic name

Comment: Your answer makes the terraform tag valuable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Worked correctly this way:

```
{
  "name": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/jobs/snapshots",
  "pubsubTarget": {
    "topicName": "projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/disk-snapshot-function-trigger",
    "attributes": {
      "num_backups": "5",
      "project": "PROJECT_ID"
    }
  },
  "schedule": "0 19 * * *",
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
}
```

or with Terraform:

```
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "snapshot_schedule" {
  provider  = "google-beta"
  name      = "snapshots"
  schedule  = "${var.snapshot_schedule}"
  time_zone = "America/Los_Angeles"
  project   = "${var.project_id}"

  pubsub_target {
    topic_name = "projects/${var.project_id}/topics/${google_pubsub_topic.trigger_disk_snapshot_function_pubsub.name}"
    data       = "${base64encode("{\"project\":\"${var.project_id}\", \"num_backups\":\"${var.num_backups}\"}")}"
  }
}
```